# Delete multiple elements from a list

Tags: elixir

Given this list:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

how can I return a new list that has these elements?

```
[3,4,5]
```

I know I use `List.delete/2` but as for as I can tell that will only delete 1 element at a time. I want to remove the first two elements in one fell swoop.

Comment: `List.drop/2` ?

Comment: That appears to be in the `Enum` module but works perfect all the same. Thanks @Dogbert

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5] -- [1,2]`   ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
# Example with static values
iex> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -- [1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]

# Example with Enum.drop/2, with multiple values
iex> Enum.drop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
[3, 4, 5]
iex> Enum.drop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], -2)
[1, 2, 3]
iex> Enum.drop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 20)
[]
iex> Enum.drop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], -20)
[]
```

You can use `List.delete/2` only can delete one at time and `Enum.drop/2` can delete multiple depend how you use it.

Comment: This only works if you know the values of the items you want removed. I feel like OP used a static list only to show the input and output of what they want. `Enum.drop/2` can remove multiple elements. That is the point of the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove elements based on some arbitrary condition, you can use [`Enum.reject/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2), and provide the reject condition as an argument.

```elixir
iex(1)> Enum.reject([1,2,3,4,5], fn x -> x in [1,2] end)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

To withdraw only first 2 elements: you can pattern match like that:

```
[_,_|sublist] = list
```

you can also use `tl/1` twice:

```
list |> tl() |> tl ()
```

However this last solution does not do it in one fell swoop.

If the number of elements to drop varies, I do not see another solution that the one @Dogbert suggested: to use [`Enum.drop/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#drop/2), or also [`Enum.split/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split/2) like that:

```
{_,sublist} = Enum.split(list,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, which could be dynamic based on your implementation is `Enum.filter/2`

It would look something like this:

```
Enum.filter(list, &(&1 >= 3))

=> [3,4,5]
```